# Asking the user to run the program again using a simple while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to run this program. After the user inputs the values, the program will output the values. my question is that the program is supposed to ask the user to enter any number to run the program again or -1 to quit, but I couldn't figure where to place the while loop in the code. I need to know where to place the while loop exactly. Should it be at the beginning of the java code or at the end. The code is below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Program4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

        //Declare variables
        double numb;
        double absolute, meanNum = 0, medianNum = 0;
        double num1, num2, num3;
        double m;
        double me;
        double ab;

        System.out.println("Enter a number"); //prompting the user to enter information
        numb = input.nextDouble();

        while (numb != -1) {

            ab = absolute(numb);
            System.out.printf("The absolute number is %f\n", ab); //prompting the user to enter information

            System.out.println("Enter three numbers"); //prompting the user to enter information
            num1 = input.nextDouble();
            num2 = input.nextDouble();
            num3 = input.nextDouble();

            m = meanNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Mean Number
            System.out.printf("The Mean Number is: %f\n", m);

            me = medianNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Median Number
            System.out.printf("The median Number is %f\n", me);
        }
    }
    //// Creating another method for finding Mean Number
    public static double meanNum(double num1, double num2, double num3) {
        double meanNumb = 0;
        meanNumb = (num1 + num2 + num3) / 3; // Calculating the mean number by summing the numbers entered divided by three

        return (meanNumb);
    }
    // Creating another method for finding Median Number
    public static double medianNum(double num1, double num2, double num3) {
        //Using the IF Statement to find the median value of three numbers entered
        double medianNum = 0;
        if (num1 < (num3) && (num1 > num2))
            medianNum = num1;
        if ((num2 < num1) && (num2 > num3))
            medianNum = num2;
        if ((num3 < num2) && (num3 > num1))
            medianNum = num3;
        if ((num1 < num2) && (num1 > num3))
            medianNum = num1;
        if ((num2 < num3) && (num2 > num1))
            medianNum = num2;
        if ((num3 < num1) && (num3 > num2))
            medianNum = num3;

        return (medianNum);
    }
    // Creating a separated method for finding the absolute value of a number
    public static double absolute(double numb) {
        double ab = 0;
        if (numb < 0) {
            ab = numb * -1;
        } else {
            ab = numb;


        }

        return ab;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do-while` loops are what you are looking for. It would be something like this:

```
do {
// whatever
} while(numb != 1);
```

`do-while` loops make sure the loop runs at least once and then depending on your `while` statement, they would either keep going or exit. So You can place the following lines within the `do-while` loop:

```
System.out.println("Enter a number"); //prompting the user to enter information
numb = input.nextDouble();
```

And after this simply include everything your `while` loop already has in it. Every time the loop runs, it will ask the user to *Enter a number* and depending on what number they enter, your program will either keep running or quit.

You can look up Oracle's tutorial for that here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

**Update:**

There is a chance you will run into some exceptions upon running this program. I would suggest you do the following to avoid any problems:

```
do {
     System.out.print("Enter a number (Enter -1 to exit): "); //prompting the user to enter information
     numb = input.nextDouble();


     if (numb != -1) {
         ab = absolute(numb);
         System.out.printf("The absolute number is %f\n", ab); //prompting the user to enter information

         System.out.println("Enter three numbers"); //prompting the user to enter information
         num1 = input.nextDouble();
         num2 = input.nextDouble();
         num3 = input.nextDouble();

         m = meanNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Mean Number
         System.out.printf("The Mean Number is: %f\n", m);

         me = medianNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Median Number
         System.out.printf("The median Number is %f\n", me);
     }
} while (numb != -1);
```

The `if-statement` makes sure the rest of the code only runs if the user entered a number other than `-1`.

Comment: Alright. I placed the do before `System.out.println("Enter a number)` , and while after `System.out.println("If you want to run the program again, press any number or -1 to quit");` See a link of a photo of the output please. The while loop did not work for some reason. http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2014-03-21_at_1.16.19_AM-qZZvBE4J.png

Comment: @user3444913 Okay, is it doing what you wanted it to do? If there's a problem with it or you don't understand something, leave a comment here and I'll help you out with it.

Comment: The while loop isn't working as you can see in the picture I attached in my previous comment. The program runs again even though I wrote -1

Comment: @user3444913 See my **Update**, it should run if you follow the code as I show in my update. Let me know if that works for you. You can also show me how you updated your code (that you attached the image to) and I'll tell you what might have been wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a message at the end of the while loop that you have to ask the user for another input and read that input into `numb` again as below.

```
System.out.println("Enter a number");
numb = input.nextDouble();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DO While loop, which is exit controlled, unlike while loop which is entry controlled

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );

    //Declare variables
    double numb;
    double absolute, meanNum = 0, medianNum = 0;
    double num1, num2, num3;
    double m;
    double me;
    double ab;



    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a number"); //prompting the user to enter information
        numb = input.nextDouble();
        ab = absolute(numb);
        System.out.printf("The absolute number is %f\n", ab); //prompting the user to enter information

        System.out.println("Enter three numbers"); //prompting the user to enter information
        num1 = input.nextDouble();
        num2 = input.nextDouble();
        num3 = input.nextDouble();

        m = meanNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Mean Number
        System.out.printf("The Mean Number is: %f\n", m);

        me = medianNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Median Number
        System.out.printf("The median Number is %f\n", me);
    } while (numb != -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `do.. while` loop!

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a number"); //prompting the user to enter information
    numb = input.nextDouble();

    ab = absolute(numb);
    System.out.printf("The absolute number is %f\n", ab); //prompting the user to enter information

    System.out.println("Enter three numbers"); //prompting the user to enter information
    num1 = input.nextDouble();
    num2 = input.nextDouble();
    num3 = input.nextDouble();

    m = meanNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Mean Number
    System.out.printf("The Mean Number is: %f\n", m);

    me = medianNum(num1, num2, num3); // Calling the method Median Number
    System.out.printf("The median Number is %f\n", me);
} while (numb != -1);
```